# Moving from `prototype` and `new` to a closure-and-exposure pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, closures, prototypal-inheritance

I have been re-factoring someone else's JavaScript code.

**BEFORE:**

```
function SomeObj(flag) {
    var _private = true;
    this.flag = (flag) ? true : false;
    this.version="1.1 (prototype)";
    if (!this._someProperty) this._init();
            // leading underscore hints at what should be a 'private' to me
    this.reset(); // assumes reset has been added...
}

SomeObj.prototype.reset = function() {
    /* perform some actions */
}

/* UPDATE */
SomeObj.prototype.getPrivate = function() {
    return _private; // will return undefined
}

/* ...several other functions appended via `prototype`...*/
```

**AFTER:**

```
var SomeObj = function (flag) {
    var _private = true;
    this.flag = (flag) ? true : false;
    this.version = "2.0 (constructor)";

    this.reset = function () {
       /* perform some actions */
    };

    /* UPDATE */
    this.getPrivate = function() {
        return _private; // will return true
    }

    /* other functions and function calls here */
}
```

For me the first example looks difficult to read, especially in a larger context. Adding methods like `reset` on like this, using the `prototype` property, seems much less controlled as it can presumably happen anywhere in the script. My refactored code (the second example above) looks much neater to me and is therefore easier to read because it's self-contained. I've gained some privacy with the variable declarations but I've lost the possibilities the prototype chain.

...

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Firstly, I'm interested to know what else I have lost by foregoing `prototype`, or if there are larger implications to the loss of the prototype chain. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristoffer/archive/2007/02/13/javascript-prototype-versus-closure-execution-speed.aspx) is 6 years old but claims that using the `prototype` property is much more efficient on a large scale than closure patterns.
2. Both the examples above would still be instantiated by a `new` operator; they are both 'classical'-ish constructors. Eventually I'd even like to move away from this into a model where all the properties and functions are declared as `var`s and I have one method which I expose that's capable of returning an object opening up all the properties and methods I need, *which have privileges (by virtue of closure) to those that are private*. Something like this:

   ```
   var SomeObj = (function () {

       /* all the stuff mentioned above, declared as 'private' `var`s */

       /* UPDATE */
       var getPrivate = function () {
           return private;
       }

       var expose = function (flag) {
            // just returns `flag` for now
            // but could expose other properties
            return {
                flag: flag || false, // flag from argument, or default value
                getPrivate: getPrivate
            } 
       };

       return {
           expose: expose
       }
   })(); // IIFE

   // instead of having to write `var whatever = new SomeObj(true);` use...
   var whatever = SomeObj.expose();
   ```

   There are a few answers on StackOverflow addressing the 'prototype vs. closure' question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564238/object-oriented-javascript-with-prototypes-vs-closures?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719926/whats-wrong-with-this-style-of-coding-javascript-closures-vs-prototypes), for example). But, as with the `prototype` property, I'm interested in what a move towards this and away from the `new` operator means for the efficiency of my code and for any loss of possibility (e.g. `instanceof` is lost). If I'm not going to be using prototypal inheritance anyway, do I actually lose anything in foregoing the `new` operator?
3. A looser question if I'm permitted, given that I'm asking for specifics above: if `prototype` and `new` really are the most efficient way to go, with more advantages (whatever you think they might be) than closure, are there any guidelines or design patterns for writing them in a neater fashion?

...

## UPDATE:

Note that `expose` returns a new object each time, so this is where the instantiation happens. As I understand this, where that object refers to methods declared in the `SomeObj` closure, they are the same methods across all objects (unless overwritten). In the case of the `flag` variable (which I've now corrected), this can be inherited from the argument of `expose`, have a default value, or again refer back to a encapsulated pre-existing method or property. So there are instances of objects being produced and there is some inheritance (plus polymorphism?) going on here.

So to repeat question 2: If I'm not going to be using prototypal inheritance anyway, do I actually lose anything in foregoing the `new` operator?

Many thanks for answers so far, which have helped to clarify my question.

Comment: Since you appear to be moving in a direction implied by some discussion, I would suggest a read of this blog entry, it covers several of your concerns/question http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

Comment: With the second example you've not lost the ability to use `instanceof`, only the third one that returns plain objects cannot be tested against special inheritance.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss +1 Thanks for the link to the article. Some useful points, so far. About halfway through it and reading all the generous answers people have left here too.

Comment: General note: I've updated the code in each example to show private variables (or attempts at them) as some of you rightly pointed out that you couldn't see any.

Comment: @Bergi +1 Thanks for pointing this out. Now corrected, I hope!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the only thing you lose by not using `.prototype` is memory - each object ends up owning its own copy of the function objects defined therein.

If you only intend instantiating "small" numbers of objects this is not likely to be a big problem.

Regarding your specific questions:

1. The second comment on that linked article is highly relevant.  The author's benchmark is wrong - it's testing the overhead of running a constructor that *also* declares four inner functions.  It's *not* testing the subsequent performance of those functions.
2. Your "closure and expose" code sample is not OO, it's just a namespace with some enclosed private variables.  Since it doesn't use `new` it's no use if you ever hope to instantiate objects from it.
3. I can't answer this - "it depends" is as good an answer as you can get for this.

Comment: Your concept of OO is too strict to me. The "closure and expose" method does not use inheritance, but clearly deals with objects and methods, so how come it's not "object-oriented"? Also, inheritance and instantiation can still be achieved with `Object.create`.

Comment: @bfavaretto hmm, it's weird code, to be sure.  For a start, there's no way to set the `flag` state.

Comment: @bfavaretto and by "not OO" I was mostly referring to the inability to create multiple instances of `SomeObj`, and not inheritence.  There's only one instance, and any variable created with `SomeObj.expose()` will share the same closure, hence the same state.

Comment: That's true, there's no inheritance there, and no multiple instances. And I agree that code is weird, I've never seen that pattern before, where you need to call `expose` (why not expose stuff directly from the IIFE, right?). Maybe I am being too picky about semantics here! :)

Comment: I've updated the question so hopefully the weird code I am suggesting makes more sense now :-) (but maybe less...) It was your comments that made me realise I still hadn't articulated my question properly so thanks.

Comment: @Altinak Well spotted on the second comment on the linked article. However, I think even before my changes the closure and exposure code was still strictly speaking OO. Just not classical OO.

Comment: @guypursey your new code is still confused - the `getPrivate` method still has the same scoping problem - i.e. it's effectively a `getPrivateStatic` method since every instance of the object returned by `SomeObj.expose()` shares the same scope for that function.

Comment: @guypursey I think you actually have one too many levels of indirection in that code.

Answer (score 1):

> What else I have lost by foregoing `prototype`?

I'm sure someone can provide an answer, but I'll at least give it a shot.  There are at least two reasons to use `prototype`:

1. `prototype` methods can be used statically
2. They are created only once

Creating a method as an object member means that it is created for every instance of the object.  That's more memory per object, and it slows down object creation (hence your efficiency).  People tend to say that `prototype` methods are like class methods whereas member methods are like object methods, but this is very misleading since methods in the prototype chain can still use the object instance.

You can define the prototype as an object itself, so you may like the syntax better (but it's not all that different):

```
SomeObj.prototype = {
    method1: function () {},
    method2: function () {}
}
```

Your argument that it seems less controlled is valid to me.  I get that it is weird to have *two* blocks involved in creating an object.  However, it's a bit spurious in that there is nothing stopping someone from overwriting the prototype of your other object anyway.

```
//Your code
var SomeObj = function (flag) { //...

//Sneaky person's code
delete SomeObj.reset;
SomeObj.prototype.reset = function () { /* what now? */ }
```

## Foregoing `new`

If you're only going to be creating specific object instances on the fly via `{}` notation, it's not really different from using `new` anyway.  You would need to use `new` to create multiple instances of the same object from a class (`function`) definition.  This is not unusual as it applies to any object oriented programming language, and it has to do with reuse.

For your current application, this may work great.  However, if you came up with some awesome plugin that was reusable across contexts, it could get annoying to have to rewrite it a lot.  I think that you are looking for something like [`require.js`](http://requirejs.org/), which allows you to define "modules" that you can import with the `require` function.  You define a module within a `define` function closure, so you get to keep the constructor and prototype definitions wrapped together anyway, and no one else can touch them until they've imported that module.

## Advantages of closure vs. `prototype`

They are not mutually exclusive:

```
var attachTo = {};
;(function (attachTo, window, document, undefined) {
    Plugin = function () { /* constructor */ };
    Plugin.prototype = { /* prototype methods */ };

    attachTo.plugin = Plugin;
})(attachTo, window, document);
var plugin = new (attachTo.plugin);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/HPjV7/1/

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer (with the clear headings!). I'm still parsing what you've written but your point about the sneaky person overwriting the code had occurred to me. It could even be unintentional, that someone writes some code further down that interferes with the prototype... Do you know of any way to prevent accidents (or sneakiness) like this from happening or is it just the nature of using an interpreted language like JavaScript? Can the prototype be "protected"?

Comment: @guypursey it has nothing to do with it being interpreted .. You could use Reflection in Java to access private members, overwrite methods, etc.  It's highly doubtful that someone will do something like this by accident, especially if they're intentionally using your API.  "Protecting" the prototype is neither impossible nor necessarily desirable.

Comment: I just figured that access to the console meant JavaScript code, being interpreted, is especially vulnerable, whereas compiled code (e.g., Java) is not vulnerable in the same way. Interesting point about reflection by the way. I have played with that in Java (a while ago) but just for calling methods. I didn't know that overwriting them, or accessing private members, was possible. Interested to hear more about "protecting" JavaScript's `prototype` though, even if only in academic sense... I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1. You already answer this question: you *loose* the prototype chain. (Actually you don't loose it, but your prototype will be always empty). The consequences are:

   - There is a little performance/memory impact, because methods are created for each instance . But it depends a lot on the JavaScript engine, and you should worry about it only if you need to create a big amount of objects.
   - You can't *monkey patch* instances by modifying the prototype. Not a big issue either, since doing that leads to a maintenance nightmare.
2. Let me do a small pedantic correction to your question: Is not a matter of "prototype vs closure", in fact the concept of closure is orthogonal to a prototype based language.

   The question is related on how you are going to create objects: define an new object from zero each time, or clone it from a prototype.

   The example that you show about using functions to limit the scope, is a usual practice in JavaScript, and you can continue doing that even if you decide to use prototypes. For example:

   ```
   var SomeObj = (function (flag) {

       /* all the stuff mentioned above, declared as 'private' `var`s */

       var MyObj = function() {}
       MyObj.prototype = {
           flag: flag,
           reset: reset
       };

       return {
          expose: function() { return new MyObj(); }
       }
   })();
   ```

   If you are worried about modularization, take a look into [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) which is an implementation of a technique called AMD (async module definition). Some people doesn't like AMD and some people love it. My experience with it was positive: it helped me a lot to create a modular JavaScript app for the browser.
3. There are some libraries to make your life with prototypes easier: [composejs](https://github.com/kriszyp/compose), [dejavu](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/dejavu), and my own [barman](https://github.com/dfernandez79/barman) (yes is a shameless self promotion, but you can look into the source code to see ways of dealing with definitions of objects).

   About patterns: Since you can easily hide object instantiation using *factory methods*, you can still use `new` to clone a prototype internally.

Answer (score 0):

Question by question:

1. Basically, having the `reset` method in the `prototype` means that all instances of your constructor will share the exact same copy of the method. By creating a local method inside the constructor, you'll have one copy of the method per instance, which will consume more memory (this may become a problem if you have a lot of instances). Other than that, both versions are identical; changing `function SomeObj` to `var SomeObj = function` only differs on how `SomeObj` is hoisted on its parent scope. You said you "gained some privacy with the variable declarations", but I didn't see any private variables there...
2. With the IIFE approach you mentioned, you'll lose the ability to check if `instance instanceof SomeObj`.
3. Not sure if this answers your question, but there is also [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), where you can still set the prototype, but get rid of the `new` keyword. You lose the ability to have constructors, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You were right that you couldn't see any private variables in the second example. I have added one now, and also added something similar to the first and third examples so they can be compared.