# Advantages of extending prototype instead of declaring whole object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, declaration

When should I use first notation:

```
var object = {
    a: function() {
        // object.a method body
    },
    b: function() {
        // object.b method body
    },
    c: function() {
        // object.c method body
    },
};
```

and when the second one?

```
function Class() {};

Class.prototype.a = function() {
    // object.a method body
};

Class.prototype.b = function() {
    // object.b method body
};

Class.prototype.c = function() {
    // object.c method body
};

var object = new Class();
```

Comment: The second one won't work.

Comment: @ciembor no, you didn't fix it yet. See my answer.

Comment: Possibly answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894807/moving-from-prototype-and-new-to-a-closure-and-exposure-pattern/14895297

Comment: Ahhh, I hate when I write faster than think;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage is that the functions are shared by all instances in second case, which makes the objects lighter. It explicitly defines the objects as instances of what is conceptually a class.

But the correct syntax is

```
function MyClass(){
}
MyClass.prototype.a = function(){
};
...
var o = new MyClass();
```

It also allows you to define an inheritance chain :

```
function OtherClass(){
}
OtherClass.prototype = new MyClass(); // makes OtherClass extend MyClass
OtherClass.prototype.b = function(){
};
...
var o2 = new OtherClass();
```

`o2` has the functions of both `OtherClass` and `MyClass`.

The MDN gives more details in its [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: I'd advise to the OP not to use `object` as a variable name. Seems ripe for error.