# Prototypical inheritance without new or Object.create

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

Is there any way whatsoever to enable an object to inherit from a prototype (1) without using `new`, and 
(2) without using `Object.create`. (I had a suspicion that new is present inside the `Object.create` method, but after the Firebug console told me it's native code, well, I have a suspicion it goes native.) When I say "inherit from a prototype" I mean **real** JavaScript prototypical inheritance (i.e, not just an imitation of it). I know real inheritance when I see it (i.e., the `__proto__` property is present, there is a circular reference between the constructor and the prototype, there is an inheritance hierarchy).

My question boils down to: even though 'we barely new ya', are the only two mechanisms for inheritance `new` and `Object.create`?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894807/moving-from-prototype-and-new-to-a-closure-and-exposure-pattern

Comment: FYI, *every* object has a `__proto__` property (in browser which support this). I don't know how one would "imitate" prototype inheritance.

Comment: @Felix objects created with literal syntax do not show a `__proto__` property in the console, while any object created with `new` does

Comment: @orb: Then you must be inspecting the object wrong. Every object (also those created via object literals) inherit from `Object.prototpye` and hence `__proto__` refers to it. Proof: http://i.imgur.com/INh3sFJ.png.

Comment: @guypursey yes the topic of that question is similar, but my question is  whether `new` and `Object.create` are the only two options for using the prototypial inheritance deliberately built into JavaScript as a design feature

Comment: @Fleix Yes, you are right about that. However, `console.log({magenta:'color', time: 'early'});` shows no `__proto__` property in the console, while objects created with new do show it. Now that I think about it, you can't even inspect the Object object, so maybe it is just the way the console s designed

Comment: Or maybe even that is the point where things go native and so their is no JavaScript to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] are the only two mechanisms for inheritance `new` and `Object.create`?

Yes, they are. At least those are the only ones you should use.

You *could* directly assign to `__proto__`, but it is not a standard property *yet*. More info: [MDN - `__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Comment: Thanks. Now I can finally put this mental debate to rest :-)

Comment: Actually to standarize or not `__proto__` is under discussion so there is no garantee it will be standarized.

Answer (score 2):

As you might know `new` and `Object.create` do a hidden action than we can call `setPrototype`.

```
Object.create = function(proto, properties) {
    var obj = {};
    setPrototype(obj, proto);
    Object.defineProperties(obj, properties);
    return obj;
}

function fakeNew(Constructor) {
    var obj = {};
    setPrototype(obj, Constructor.prototype);
    Constructor.call(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

It's not than "new is inside Object.create" or "Object.create is inside new". Both does the prototype assignation and other actions.

Actually there is a way to implement `setPrototype` but surely you know it's not standard.

```
function setPrototype(obj, proto) {
    obj.__proto__ = proto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid using the `new` operator, but still instantiate an object that inherits from a prototype (the prototype of `SomeClass`), a simple solution is to build a facade constructor function (which uses the `new` operator behind the scenes):

```
function SomeClassFacade() {
  return new SomeClass();
}

SomeClass.prototype = {
 /* ... */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ES6 you can also use `Reflect.construct`, which basically behaves like the `new` operator:

```
function Constructor() {}
var instance = Reflect.construct(Constructor, []);
Object.getPrototypeOf(instance); // Constructor.prototype
```

If you want something closer to `Object.create`, ES6 extending classes can also create inheritance, but only from constructors or `null`:

```
var obj = (class extends null{}).prototype;
delete obj.constructor;
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj); // null
```

```
function Constructor() {}
var obj = (class extends Constructor{}).prototype;
delete obj.constructor;
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj); // Constructor.prototype
```